# change color of `UITableViewCell` once shown in screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to change the color of the `UITableViewCell` once it is shown on the screen to reflect something like the read/unread behaviour. For example:

User will be seeing a list which will be firstly of lets say red color then after some time the color should be changed to clearColor. When user scrolls down the new cell should again be red for a limited time and then change to clearColor.

Comment: And what have you tried? This is fairly basic, I’m sure there is already an answer to that, if you search for it.

Comment: @Losiowaty I tried changing color in `willDisplayCell` but didn't help. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

**Swift**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell,
               forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {

        if let cel = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) { // not used cell directly because it may be nil at this moment

            cel.backgroundColor = UIColor.red // save this state in model to avoid dequeuing problems 
        }

    }

}
```

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        UITableViewCell*cel = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        cel.backgroundColor = [UIColor YourColor]; // won't ser it cel is nil

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            UITableViewCell*cel = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

            cel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; // won't ser it cel is nil

        });

    });

}
```

Comment: This will just make the color to red. I want to change the color to some color once those cells are shown with some delay. Lets say the 10 cells are shown and array has 20 so those 10 cells should be red firstly then after some delay all those 10 cells should be change to clear color and then when user scrolls and sees the 11th cell then the same should be happen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the state of each row/cell in your datasource. Since cells are reused, you shouldn't store this data in the cell itself. I presume that you have some kind of array as your tableview's datasource? So the easiest solution would be to add a property for each item in your datasource to store if the cell for a particular item has been displayed or not.

Is the idea to give each cell a default color, and the next time this cell is scrolled into view the color should be changed to indicate that it has been viewed previously?

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches for it. One of the approach will be creating an array of Boolean with all false, whose size will be equal to number of rows.

```
var array = [Bool](repeating: false, count: self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0))
           // assuming only 1 section is available
```

Inside tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath), you have to do the following:

```
array[indexPath.row] = true
```

Inside tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath), you can check the boolean value and set color:

```
if array[indexPath.row] {
    cell.backgroundColor = .red
} else {
    cell.backgroundColor = .blue
}
```

Comment: I don't have any functionality of selection. User will be seeing a list which will be firstly of lets say red color then after some time the color should be changed to clearColor and when user scrolls he should see those new cell as red and then change to clearColor